# no adapter attached skipping layout rows in dataset are displayed but not with values from server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have 50 rows in dataset  which are being displayed in the recyclerview but the values for server are not being set. here is my code. !! and is not duplicate because i tried out other solutions provided but none worked for me.

fragment **Live.java**

```
package com.pamojamedia.futaaapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Fidelia on 1/15/2016.
 */
public class Live extends Fragment {


    private RecyclerView liveRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private LiveAdapter liveAdapter;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    private CacheRequest cacheRequest, refresh;
    private String api_url = "http://www.futaa.com/json/7wviyWzZAoSZBzDofzArBwvSa9tSZBB009VDqyPy/upcoming";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live_fragment, container, false);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        //layout manager
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        swipe.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue);

        liveRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.live_recyclerview);

        liveRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        liveRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        liveRecyclerView.setAdapter(liveAdapter);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {refreshContent();
            }
        });

        //cached volley
        cacheRequest = new CacheRequest(0, api_url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                try {
                    String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        liveAdapter = new LiveAdapter(getActivity(), parseResult(jsonString));



                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    liveRecyclerView.setAdapter(liveAdapter);
                    liveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }


        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError || error instanceof AuthFailureError || error instanceof ServerError
                        || error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No connection ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "problem fetching data ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(cacheRequest);
        return view;
    }

    private List<LiveData> parseResult(String jsonString) throws ParseException, JSONException {
        List <LiveData> liveDataList  = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject liveItems = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONArray liveArray = liveItems.getJSONArray("events");

        //JSONObject data = liveArray.getJSONObject(i);
        for (int i = 0; i < liveArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject data = liveArray.getJSONObject(i);


            //getting the variables




            int id = data.optInt("id");
            String homeTeamImgUrl = "http://www.futaa.com//images/650x383_cropped/wat.jpg";
            String awayTeamImgUrl = "http://www.futaa.com//images/650x383_cropped/wat.jpg";
            String homeTeamName = data.optString("home_team");
            String awayTeamName = data.optString("away_team");
            String eventTime = data.optString("time");
            String eventUrl = data.optString("url");
            String eventInfo = data.optString("info");

            LiveData livedata = new LiveData(id, eventInfo, eventTime, eventUrl, homeTeamName, awayTeamName, homeTeamImgUrl, awayTeamImgUrl);


            //setting the variables
            livedata.setId(id);
            livedata.setHomeTeamName(homeTeamName);
            livedata.setAwayTeamName(awayTeamName);
            livedata.setHomeTeamImgUrl(homeTeamImgUrl);
            livedata.setAwayTeamImgUrl(awayTeamImgUrl);
            livedata.setEventUrl(eventUrl);
            livedata.setEventTime(eventTime);
            livedata.setEventInfo(eventInfo);


            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), homeTeamName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            liveDataList.add(livedata);

        }


        return liveDataList;

    }

    //refresh
    private void refreshContent() {
        refresh = new CacheRequest(0, api_url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    liveAdapter = new LiveAdapter(getActivity(), parseResult(jsonObject.toString()));

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Loading .... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    liveRecyclerView.setAdapter(liveAdapter);
                    liveAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError || error instanceof AuthFailureError || error instanceof ServerError
                        || error instanceof NetworkError || error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No connection ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "problem fetching data ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        requestQueue.add(refresh);
    }

   //caching class
    public class CacheRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
        private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
        private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

        public CacheRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, errorListener);
            this.mListener = listener;
            this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        }


        @Override
        protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
            if (cacheEntry == null) {
                cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
            }
            final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
            final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
            final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
            cacheEntry.data = response.data;
            cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
            cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
            String headerValue;
            headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
            if (headerValue != null) {
                cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
            }
            headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
            if (headerValue != null) {
                cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
            }
            cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
            return Response.success(response, cacheEntry);
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            mListener.onResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
            return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
        }

        @Override
        public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
            mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
        }
    }


}
```

then my adapter **LiveAdapter.java**

```
package com.pamojamedia.futaaapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.GlideDrawable;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class LiveAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveAdapter.MyViewHolder1> {

    private static final int TYPE_LIST = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_AD = 1;


    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater liveInflater;
    private List<LiveData> liveDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public LiveAdapter(Context context, List<LiveData> liveDataList) {
        liveInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.liveDataList = liveDataList;
    }

    public void setLiveDataList(ArrayList<LiveData> liveDataList) {
        this.liveDataList = liveDataList;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, liveDataList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder1 onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,  int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater liveInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            View view = liveInflater.inflate(R.layout.live_custom_row, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder1 holder = null;
            try {
                holder = new MyViewHolder1(view, viewType, context);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return holder;
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_AD) {
            View view = liveInflater.inflate(R.layout.advert_view, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder1 holder = null;
            try {
                holder = new MyViewHolder1(view, viewType, context);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return holder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder1 holder, int i) {
       LiveData livecurrent = liveDataList.get(i);
        if (holder.view_type == TYPE_LIST) {

            //setting the event values
            holder.id = livecurrent.getId();
            holder.eventTime = livecurrent.getEventTime();
            holder.eventUrl = livecurrent.getEventUrl();
            holder.homeTeamImgUrl = livecurrent.getHomeTeamImgUrl();
            holder.awayTeamImgUrl = livecurrent.getAwayTeamImgUrl();
            holder.homeTeamName.setText(livecurrent.getHomeTeamName());
            holder.awayTeamName.setText(livecurrent.getAwayTeamName());
            holder.eventInfo.setText(livecurrent.getEventInfo());
            Toast.makeText(context, livecurrent.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //glide image loading 1
            //glide
            if (holder.context != null) {
                Glide.with(holder.context).load(livecurrent.getHomeTeamImgUrl())
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                return false;
                            }
                        }).override(800, 530)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.team1)
                        .into(holder.liveFirstImage);
            }
            //end glide

            //glide image loading 2
            //glide
            if (holder.context != null) {
                Glide.with(holder.context).load(livecurrent.getAwayTeamImgUrl())
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                                return false;
                            }
                        }).override(800, 530)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.team2)
                        .into(holder.liveSecondImage);
            }
            //end glide


        } else if (holder.view_type == TYPE_AD) {
            //

        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return liveDataList == null ? 0 : liveDataList.size();
    }

    //get view type
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 2 || position == 8 || position == 14 || position == 20 || position == 26 || position == 32 || position == 38 || position == 44 || position == 50) {
            return TYPE_AD;
        } else {
            return TYPE_LIST;
        }
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public int view_type;
        public Context context;
        public TextView homeTeamName, awayTeamName, eventInfo, liveCategory;
        public ImageView liveFirstImage, liveSecondImage;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;
        public int id;
        public String homeTeamImgUrl;
        public String awayTeamImgUrl;
        public String eventUrl;
        public String eventTime;

        public MyViewHolder1(View itemView, int viewType, Context c) throws ParseException {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            itemView.setClickable(true);

            if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
                id = 0;
                homeTeamImgUrl = "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-dZ2LhrpNpxs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAy-M/iHnTK_2LdSA/s0-c-k-no-ns/photo.jpg";
                awayTeamImgUrl = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-iDzlv7IG4rY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAACm-I/vS-3cffMf7E/s0-c-k-no-ns/photo.jpg";
                eventUrl = "http://www.futaa.com//images/650x383_cropped/wat.jpg";
                eventTime = "http://www.futaa.com//images/650x383_cropped/wat.jpg";

                //images
                liveFirstImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.liveFirstImage);
                liveSecondImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.liveSecondImage);
                //date
                eventInfo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventInfo);
                //text views
                homeTeamName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeTeamName);
                awayTeamName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayTeamName);
                liveCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.liveCategory);
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //intent
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LiveDetails.class);
                        //bundling
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        //strings
                        bundle.putString("awayTeamImgUrl", awayTeamImgUrl);
                        bundle.putString("homeTeamImgUrl", homeTeamImgUrl);
                        bundle.putString("eventInfo", eventInfo.getText().toString());
                        bundle.putString("liveCategory", liveCategory.getText().toString());
                        bundle.putString("liveTime", eventInfo.getText().toString());
                        bundle.putString("liveFirstName", homeTeamName.getText().toString());
                        bundle.putString("liveSecondName", awayTeamName.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });


                view_type = 1;


            } else if (viewType == TYPE_AD) {
                //
                view_type = 3;
            }


        }

    }


}
```

**LiveData.java **

```
package com.pamojamedia.futaaapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Fidelia on 1/25/2016.
 */
public class LiveData {
    public int id;
    public String homeTeamImgUrl;
    public String awayTeamImgUrl;
    public String homeTeamName;
    public String awayTeamName;
    public String eventTime;
    public String eventUrl;
    public String eventInfo;


    public LiveData(){

    }

    public LiveData(int id, String eventInfo, String eventUrl, String eventTime, String awayTeamName, String homeTeamName, String awayTeamImgUrl, String homeTeamImgUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.eventInfo = eventInfo;
        this.eventUrl = eventUrl;
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
        this.awayTeamName = awayTeamName;
        this.homeTeamName = homeTeamName;
        this.awayTeamImgUrl = awayTeamImgUrl;
        this.homeTeamImgUrl = homeTeamImgUrl;
    }

    public String getHomeTeamImgUrl() {
        return homeTeamImgUrl;
    }

    public void setHomeTeamImgUrl(String homeTeamImgUrl) {
        this.homeTeamImgUrl = homeTeamImgUrl;
    }

    public String getAwayTeamImgUrl() {
        return awayTeamImgUrl;
    }

    public void setAwayTeamImgUrl(String awayTeamImgUrl) {
        this.awayTeamImgUrl = awayTeamImgUrl;
    }

    public String getHomeTeamName() {
        return homeTeamName;
    }

    public void setHomeTeamName(String homeTeamName) {
        this.homeTeamName = homeTeamName;
    }

    public String getAwayTeamName() {
        return awayTeamName;
    }

    public void setAwayTeamName(String awayTeamName) {
        this.awayTeamName = awayTeamName;
    }

    public String getEventTime() {
        return eventTime;
    }

    public void setEventTime(String eventTime) {
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }

    public String getEventUrl() {
        return eventUrl;
    }

    public void setEventUrl(String eventUrl) {
        this.eventUrl = eventUrl;
    }

    public String getEventInfo() {
        return eventInfo;
    }

    public void setEventInfo(String eventInfo) {
        this.eventInfo = eventInfo;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

please help. where is the problem or what am I doing wrong

Comment: did you check that your parseResult() returns correct list?

Comment: the parseResult() method returns correct results.  I managed to figure it out. i removed the getItemViewType() from the adapter and it worked like charm. thanks